# Proof that if one divisor is smaller than square root of the dividend, then other divisor is greater than the square root of the dividend.

Tags: inequality

We have, $ij = n$

Suppose, $i < \sqrt n$

Since, $j > 0$

$i j < \sqrt n j$

$n < \sqrt n  j$

$n^2 < n  j^2$

$n  < j^2$

$\sqrt n < j$

Hence proved.

Comment: To prove the opposite, read from downside up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the squaring step.

$$i<\sqrt n\iff \frac 1i>\frac1{\sqrt n}\iff j=\frac ni>\sqrt n.$$

Or you can square everything,

$$i^2<n\iff \frac 1{i^2}>\frac1n\iff j^2=\frac{n^2}{i^2}>n.$$

Comment: Oh! I could have divided by sqrt(n) in the third step.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can prove the contrapositive instead.

$(0 < a < \sqrt n) \land (0 < b \le \sqrt n) \Rightarrow (0 < ab < n) \Rightarrow (ab \ne n)$.

So $(ab = n) \Rightarrow \lnot ((0 < a < \sqrt n) \land (0 < b \le \sqrt n)) \iff ((0 < a < \sqrt n) \Rightarrow (b > \sqrt n))$

Answer (score 0):

**By contradiction:**

$$i<\sqrt n\land j\le\sqrt n\implies ij<n.$$

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: @parv: sorry, no, this is immediate.